# xCode 3.2.3 and simulator at 50 percent

Tags: iphone, xcode

This has been driving me crazy and I have searched the web but cannot find an answer.  Is it possible to set the simulator to run at 100% all of the time?

Every time I run it, it defaults to 50 percent ant it is driving me crazy!  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Geo...

Answer (score -1):

I expect you are talking of the display size.

When in xCode look for the Overview dropdown on the left upper side of the window and change from "iPad Simulator 3.2" to "iPhone Simulator 4.0".

That should do the trick :-)

Comment: This does not allow you to run the 3.2 sim in full screen 100%.  It puts the sim to iPhone Sim 4.0 -- which will immediately switch back to iPad Simulator 3.2 if you are Build-ing and Running a 3.2 app under iPad mode.

Comment: Ups... Good to know, I was doing it this way thinking that it was only the naming as I did not realize any difference.

Comment: No this is not it.  I do have it set to iPhone Simulator and still shows only as defualt 50 percent.